# Mediawiki DB connection error while attempting to upgrade - postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, mediawiki

I have a problem similar to: [MediaWiki DB connection error while attempting to upgrade to 1.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550586/mediawiki-db-connection-error-while-attempting-to-upgrade)

But on another db: PostgreSQL.

Versions:

- Mediawiki actual version: 1.19.3
- Mediawiki target version: 1.24.1
- Postgresql Version: 9.3.4
- PHP Version: 5.4.21
- OS Ubuntu x64, kernel 3.5.0-49-generic

When I run **update.php** I have error: **DB connection error: No database connection**

I have the same problem for all the wiki on this server. I have no problem for other wikis. The difference: db server in this case is not localhost.

Mediawiki database settings

```
## Database settings
$wgDBtype           = "postgres";
$wgDBserver         = "192.168.1.7";
$wgDBname           = "mywikidb";
$wgDBuser           = "mywikiuser";
$wgDBpassword       = "xxxxxxxxxx";

# Postgres specific settings
$wgDBport           = "5432";
$wgDBmwschema       = "mediawiki";
$wgDBts2schema      = "public";
```

After several attempts I returned to old wiki directory.

Then I had some errors: **Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 8006 bytes in /mypath/vafud/includes/LocalisationCache.php on line 894**

And one: **Invalid fallback '' in fallback sequence for 'it'**

So: something on database is done. Something not?

Anyway, after restoring db backup everything went fine.

Any Idea of what is wrong? Connection parameters seems ok.

Can I skip this and manually upgrade the database schema?

Thanks.

Edit:
errors found in apache error log (not sure if related):

```
2015-02-19 23:41:19 CET ERROR:  column "page_links_updated" does not exist at character 154
2015-02-19 23:41:19 CET STATEMENT:  SELECT /* WikiPage::pageData  */  page_id,page_namespace,page_title,page_restrictions,page_counter,page_is_redirect,page_is_new,page_random,page_touched,page_links_updated,page_latest,page_len,page_con
tent_model  FROM "page"   WHERE page_namespace = '0' AND page_title = 'Pagina_principale'  LIMIT 1
2015-02-19 23:42:08 CET ERROR:  column "page_links_updated" does not exist at character 154
2015-02-19 23:42:08 CET STATEMENT:  SELECT /* WikiPage::pageData  */  page_id,page_namespace,page_title,page_restrictions,page_counter,page_is_redirect,page_is_new,page_random,page_touched,page_links_updated,page_latest,page_len,page_con
tent_model  FROM "page"   WHERE page_namespace = '0' AND page_title = 'Pagina_principale'  LIMIT 1
2015-02-20 00:06:43 CET ERROR:  column "rc_source" does not exist at character 206
2015-02-20 00:06:43 CET STATEMENT:  SELECT /* SpecialRecentChanges::doMainQuery 84.15.216.161 */  rc_id,rc_timestamp,rc_user,rc_user_text,rc_namespace,rc_title,rc_comment,rc_minor,rc_bot,rc_new,rc_cur_id,rc_this_oldid,rc_last_oldid,rc_t
ype,rc_source,rc_patrolled,rc_ip,rc_old_len,rc_new_len,rc_deleted,rc_logid,rc_log_type,rc_log_action,rc_params,(SELECT  array_to_string(array_agg(ct_tag),',')  FROM "change_tag"   WHERE ct_rc_id=rc_id  ) AS ts_tags  FROM "recentchanges"
  WHERE rc_bot = '0' AND (rc_timestamp >= '2015-02-12 00:00:00 GMT') AND rc_new IN ('0','1')   ORDER BY rc_timestamp DESC LIMIT 50
```

Also: link to wiki (in Italian) if useful: http://www.vafud.com/

Comment: First: look in the postgres logfile to see if the connection was successful. If it was the error is either in the (changed?) database structure or in the (changed?) application. Or both.

Comment: I will dig deeper in the log in the evening and will post relevants entry.

Comment: Postgresql log added.

Comment: As you can see from the log, the connection to the DB was successful, but the wiki-app attemts to retrieve columns that dont exist. Most probably the software assumes a different (newer?) version of the data, with more/different columns in the DB.

Comment: Yes, but this work must be done by update.php...

Comment: Maybe update.php assumed the wrong version(s) Or it assumed the model to be in a different schema. Or it just failed. (The logfile fragment is for running update.php, or running the actual wiki-code?)

Comment: Unfortunately [that version of the source code](http://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.19/) is no longer hosted. If you have the line number its failing at though, you can open that file and follow the function calls backwards and get a pretty good idea as to what happened. Whenever I have a bad pre-rolled-something update, I try to remember to double back over the entire file structure to make sure there aren't any extra "new" files lingering. Wordpress, for example is really bad about throwing red herrings due to that.

Comment: Has the postgres user enough permissions to update the design of the tables?

Comment: @LoekBergman yes, and there are no errors in the log.

Comment: I read a little about it, and I found this: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Database_error_in_upgrading_from_1.18_to_1.22

Comment: I'm going to read it, thanks